# Stack Overflow blog issue gives users the ability to reply to unapproved comments

Tags: bug, blog

Following a direct link to comment that is unapproved (like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/12/practical-ways-to-write-better-javascript/?unapproved=332355&moderation-hash=1a61affce163430131769aaa6023a0a4#comment-332355)), shows an option to reply. Is it a feature or a bug?

Comment: I've just [left a test comment](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/12/practical-ways-to-write-better-javascript/?unapproved=3118531&moderation-hash=3c6c7461e73cb1fa1d6358bec5a256e1#comment-3118531) on that same blog post to see if this is still occurring. Looking at it in an incognito window, I see the comment that's awaiting moderation, but it doesn't seem like a "Reply" link appears below it. Can you confirm that this issue is no longer occurring?

Comment: Since this problem doesn't appear to be occurring anymore, I'll close this as "no longer reproducible" and remove the status-review tag. Feel free to reopen/reescalate the issue if it's still happening.